# SystemError: <class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, opencv

This is the code used.

```
configpath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weigthpath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weigthpath, configpath)
```

[image: Picture of error]

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide all your files and also paste the error message. Thank you.

Comment: @NavanK. <class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'> returned a result with an error set

Comment: @孙Gleen were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There's wrong with your files. I also have the same error. I solved it.

I solved it by replacing the ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt and frozen_inference_graph.pb files with the files that are downloaded from OpenCV documentation. If you fail to found them in OpenCV documentation, I can provide them for you.

i also got this problem during my project work(in eclipse IDE). i found work around that,

> Both files must be in your project folder
>
> *if both files in project folder and still not solve* than try **open with** any editor you are using in my case it is sublime and notepad,
> means you have to **set default file opener** for ***.pb** and
> ***.pbtxt**.

it solved error: *<class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'> returned a result with an error set*.

**after solving** this error, **if(and only if)** you get this,

> *error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't create layer "FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV3/Conv/hard_swish/add" of type "AddV2" in
> function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20191202::LayerData::getLayerInstance'*

Than upgrade your opencv,

> pip install --upgrade opencv-python

in case you want to [Download Files](https://github.com/sidpro-hash/Object-Detection).

Comment: if it solve your problem than up vote and accept.