# OpenCV System Error<class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, system-error

**Tried to load the config and weights file in OpenCV's dnn_DetectionModel**,
But it shows this error.
Upgraded OpenCV to its latest version using `pip install --upgrade opencv-python` but it's still showing the error.
The files are all in the same folder

```
import cv2 as cv
config_file= 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
frozen_model= 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'
model= cv.dnn_DetectionModel(frozen_model, config_file)
```

[Shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIPH8.png)

```
class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63750666/systemerror-class-cv2-dnn-detectionmodel-returned-a-result-with-an-error-se

Comment: @Luiz yes. I made the default opening app for .pb and .pbtxt files to Jupyter Notebook