# Python website flask Object Detected in SystemError: <class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I'm making object recognition using Python flask.
this is my code

```
        c_Names = []
        c_File = 'coco.names'
        with open(c_File,'rt') as f:
            c_Names = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

        confPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
        weiPath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'
        net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weiPath, confPath)
        net.setInputSize(320,320)
        net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
        net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
        net.setInputSwapRB(True)
        packet,_ = self.client_socket.recvfrom(self.BUFF_SIZE)
        data = base64.b64decode(packet,' /')
        npdata = np.fromstring(data,dtype=np.uint8)
        frame = cv2.imdecode(npdata,1)
        # DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH TENSORFLOW / KERAS AND OPENCV
        classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(frame, confThreshold=0.5)
        print(classIds, bbox)
        if len(classIds) != 0:
            for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
                cv2.rectangle(frame,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
                cv2.putText(frame, c_Names[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10, box[1]+30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0), 2)
                cv2.putText(frame, str(round(confidence*100,2)),(box[0]+200, box[1]+30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0), 2)
                print("Name : " + c_Names[classId-1]+"\next : " + str(round(confidence*100,2) ))
        
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        data = None #Data is information about classification in json form or dict
        self.__send_frame(data if data != None else {"data": "data"})
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

but if i do it
`SystemError: <class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'>` returned a result with an error set.

I'm frozen_inference_graph.Even though the pb was reinstalled, it was not fixed.
What should I do?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Open_Cv\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 462, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "D:\Open_Cv\anaconda\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers\response.py", line 50, in _iter_encoded    for item in iterable:
  File "C:\Opencv_Object_detect_platform-main\OBJweb\app_stable.py", line 16, in gen
    frame = camera.get_frame()
  File "C:\Opencv_Object_detect_platform-main\OBJweb\camera\camera.py", line 41, in get_frame
    net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weiPath, confPath)
SystemError: <class 'cv2.dnn_DetectionModel'> returned a result with an error set
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2022 23:13:00] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Did you check similar posts like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458381/18667225 ?

Comment: already try this